# lrm formula with rcs

Tags: r

I am attempting to use the rms::lrm function to fit a logistic regression model where I apply the rcs function to one variable, and also use the rest of the variables in the dataset.

For example, I want to do the following:

```
fit = rms::lrm(y~ rcs(a) + ., data=myData, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
```

However, this returns the following error:

> Error in if (!length(fname) || !any(fname==zname)) { : missing value
>   where TRUE/FALSE needed

I have tried several different permutations of the formula, but nothing else produces an error.

The following examples work without error:

```
fit = rms::lrm(y~ rcs(a), data=myData, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
fit = rms::lrm(y~ ., data=myData, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
```

Is there any convenient way to apply rcs() to specific variables and still use the "." operator, or do I need to manually type out every other variable simply because I'm using rcs()?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't use the "."  operator, but I sometimes use a paste/collapse to generate the list of variables to include. In your case something like this:

```
#get all the columns except for 'a'
linearvars <- setdiff(colnames(data),'a')
linearphrase <- paste(linearvars, collapse=" + ")

#combine the linear terms with the rest of the formula
fullformula <- as.formula( paste0('y~rcs(a) + ', linearphrase) )
```

or as a single line:

```
fullformula <- as.formula(paste0('y~rcs(a) + ', paste(setdiff(colnames(data), 'a'), collapse=" + ")))
```